Unable to correctly render images in NextJS after exiting Full Screen Mode
Facing an issue in rendering images. When I enter in Full Screen Mode and move to the last image, and then cancels the full screen mode, image slide render breaks along with wrong pagination number, as shown in attached in first screenshot. Help me out in resolving this issue.

Originally, image slide along with pagination is shown in second screenshot:

CODE:
"use client";

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import NextImage from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselContent,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselNext,
  CarouselPrevious,
} from "@/components/ui/carousel";
import { EnterFullScreenIcon, ExitFullScreenIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";

export default function PropertyImages({ propertyImages }) {
  const [api, setApi] = React.useState();
  const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(1);
  const [isFullScreen, setIsFullScreen] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!api) return;

    api.on("select", () => {
      setCurrent(api.selectedScrollSnap() + 1);
    });
  }, [api]);

  // Function to toggle full-screen mode
  const handleFullScreen = () => {
    const carouselElement = document.getElementById("carousel-container");
    carouselElement.onfullscreenchange = () => {
      setIsFullScreen(document.fullscreenElement !== null);
      // Clamp the current index to be within bounds of the propertyImages array
      if (document.fullscreenElement === null) {
        setCurrent((prev) => Math.min(prev, propertyImages.length));
      }
    };

    if (!isFullScreen) {
      if (carouselElement.requestFullscreen) {
        carouselElement.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (carouselElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        // Firefox
        carouselElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (carouselElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        // Chrome, Safari, and Opera
        carouselElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (carouselElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
        // IE/Edge
        carouselElement.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
    } else {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        // Firefox
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        // Chrome, Safari, and Opera
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        // IE/Edge
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      id="carousel-container"
      className={cn(
        "w-full p-0 lg:mt-10 mt-0",
        isFullScreen ? "fixed inset-0 bg-black z-50" : "lg:h-[450px] h-full"
      )}
    >
      <Carousel
        opts={{
          align: "start",
          loop: false,
        }}
        setApi={setApi}
        className="w-full h-full"
      >
        <CarouselContent
          className={cn(
            "items-center ml-0 transition-transform ease-linear",
            isFullScreen ? "h-full" : "lg:h-[450px] h-full"
          )}
        >
          {propertyImages.map((item, index) => (
            <CarouselItem
              key={index}
              className={cn(
                "items-center transition-all  ease-linear relative pl-0",
                current === index
                  ? `${
                      isFullScreen
                        ? "basis-full    p-2 h-screen "
                        : "lg:basis-3/5 lg:h-[450px] px-2 h-96"
                    } `
                  : `${
                      isFullScreen
                        ? "basis-full  p-2 h-screen "
                        : "lg:basis-1/5 lg:h-[210px] h-96"
                    }`
              )}
              id={`image-${index}`}
            >
              <>
                {item.title && index === current && (
                  <div className="absolute top-5 left-5 bg-black bg-opacity-40 py-2 hidden sm:block px-4 rounded-lg">
                    <p className="text-white">{item.title}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
                {item.title && (
                  <div className="absolute top-5 left-5 bg-black bg-opacity-40 py-1  sm:hidden px-4 rounded-lg">
                    <p className="text-white">{item.title}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
                {isFullScreen ? (
                  <NextImage
                    src={item.url}
                    width={1500}
                    height={1500}
                    alt="product image"
                    className="h-full w-full object-contain aspect-auto bg-white border border-border rounded-xl"
                  />
                ) : (
                  <NextImage
                    src={item.url}
                    width={500}
                    height={500}
                    alt="product image"
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover aspect-auto bg-white border border-border rounded-xl"
                  />
                )}
                {/* Fullscreen button */}
                {current == index ? (
                  isFullScreen ? (
                    <button
                      className="absolute bottom-5 right-5 z-10 bg-black bg-opacity-40 p-2 rounded-full  hidden sm:block  text-white hover:bg-opacity-60 transition-all duration-300"
                      onClick={handleFullScreen}
                    >
                      <ExitFullScreenIcon width={20} height={20} />
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <button
                      className="absolute bottom-5 right-5 bg-black bg-opacity-40 p-2 rounded-full hidden sm:block  text-white hover:bg-opacity-60 transition-all duration-300"
                      onClick={handleFullScreen}
                    >
                      <EnterFullScreenIcon width={20} height={20} />
                    </button>
                  )
                ) : null}
              </>
            </CarouselItem>
          ))}
        </CarouselContent>

        <CarouselPrevious
          id="prev-image"
          className="top-1/2 -rotate-90 transition-all duration-500 -translate-y-1/2 -left-1"
        />
        <CarouselNext
          id="next-image"
          className="top-1/2 rotate-90 -right-1 transition-all duration-500 -translate-y-1/2 left-auto"
        />

        {isFullScreen ? (
          <button
            className="absolute bottom-5 right-5 z-10 bg-black bg-opacity-40 p-2 rounded-full sm:hidden  text-white hover:bg-opacity-60 transition-all duration-300"
            onClick={handleFullScreen}
          >
            <ExitFullScreenIcon width={20} height={20} />
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button
            className="absolute bottom-5 right-5 bg-black bg-opacity-40 p-2 rounded-full sm:hidden text-white hover:bg-opacity-60 transition-all duration-300"
            onClick={handleFullScreen}
          >
            <EnterFullScreenIcon width={20} height={20} />
          </button>
        )}
      </Carousel>
      {isFullScreen && (
        <button
          className="absolute top-5 right-5 z-50 bg-black bg-opacity-40 p-2 rounded-full text-white hover:bg-opacity-60 transition-all duration-300"
          onClick={handleFullScreen}
        >
          <ExitFullScreenIcon width={20} height={20} />
        </button>
      )}

      <div className="py-2 text-center flex justify-center items-center text-sm text-muted-foreground">
        <span> {current} / </span>
        <span className="hidden md:block">
          {" "}
          {propertyImages.length - 2}
        </span>{" "}
        <span className="block md:hidden"> {propertyImages.length}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


